# spring kafka template producer performance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka template for producing messages. And the rate at which it is producing the messages is too slow. Takes around 8 mins for producing 15000 messages.

Following is How I created the Kafka template:

```
 @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> highSpeedAvroProducerFactory(
      @Qualifier("highSpeedProducerProperties") KafkaProperties properties) {
    final Map<String, Object> kafkaPropertiesMap = properties.getKafkaPropertiesMap();
    System.out.println(kafkaPropertiesMap);
    kafkaPropertiesMap.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    kafkaPropertiesMap.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroGenericSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaPropertiesMap);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> highSpeedAvroKafkaTemplate(
      @Qualifier("highSpeedAvroProducerFactory") ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> highSpeedAvroProducerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(highSpeedAvroProducerFactory);
  }
```

Here is how I am using the template to send the messages:

```
@Async("servicingPlatformUpdateExecutor")
  public void afterWrite(List<? extends Account> items) {
    LOGGER.info("Batch start:{}",items.size());
    for (Test test : items) {
        if (test.isOmega()) {

          ObjectKeyRecord objectKeyRecord = ObjectKeyRecord.newBuilder().setType("test").setId(test.getId()).build();
          LOGGER.info("build start, {}",test.getId());

          GenericRecord message = MessageUtils.buildEventRecord(
              schemaService.findSchema(topicName)
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new OmegaException("SchemaNotFoundException", topicName)), objectKeyRecord, test);
          LOGGER.info("build end, {}",account.getId());
          LOGGER.info("send Started , {}",account.getId());
          ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, GenericRecord>> future = highSpeedAvroKafkaTemplate.send(topicName, objectKeyRecord.toString(), message);
          LOGGER.info("send Done , {}",test.getId());
          future.addCallback(new KafkaProducerFutureCallback(kafkaSender, topicName, objectKeyRecord.toString(), message));
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info("Batch end}");

  }
```

Producer Properties:

```
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
bootstrap.servers = [***VALID BROKERS****))]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
interceptor.classes = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
client.id = producer-1
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
request.timeout.ms = 30000
acks = all
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
retries = 2147483647
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
compression.type = none
metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
buffer.memory = 800000000
timeout.ms = 30000
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
block.on.buffer.full = false
ssl.key.password = null
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 10
metrics.num.samples = 2
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
batch.size = 40000000
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.cipher.suites = null
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
max.request.size = 1048576
value.serializer = class com.message.serialization.AvroGenericSerializer
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
linger.ms = 2
```

Here is the log which shows call to the kakfatemplate send method takes few milliseconds:

```
2018-04-27 05:29:05.691 INFO  - testservice -  - UpdateExecutor-1 - com.test.testservice.adapter.batch.testsyncjob.UpdateWriteListener:70 - build start, 1
2018-04-27 05:29:05.691 INFO  - testservice -  - UpdateExecutor-1 - com.test.testservice.adapter.batch.testsyncjob.UpdateWriteListener:75 - build end, 1
2018-04-27 05:29:05.691 INFO  - testservice -  - UpdateExecutor-1 - com.test.testservice.adapter.batch.testsyncjob.UpdateWriteListener:76 - send Started , 1
2018-04-27 05:29:05.778 INFO  - testservice -  - UpdateExecutor-1 - com.test.testservice.adapter.batch.testsyncjob.UpdateWriteListener:79 - send Done , 1
2018-04-27 05:29:07.794 INFO  - testservice -  - kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 - com.test.testservice.adapter.batch.testsyncjob.KafkaProducerFutureCallback:38
```

Any suggestion on how can I improve the performance for the sender would be greatly appreciated

Spring Kakfa version: 1.2.3.RELEASE
Kafka client: 0.10.2.1

UPDATE 1:

Changed the Serializer to ByteArraySerializer and then produced the same.
I still see the each send method call on kafkatempate takes 100 to 200 milliseconds

```
ObjectKeyRecord objectKeyRecord = ObjectKeyRecord.newBuilder().setType("test").setId(test.getId()).build();
          GenericRecord message = MessageUtils.buildEventRecord(
              schemaService.findSchema(testConversionTopicName)
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new TestException("SchemaNotFoundException", testTopicName)), objectKeyRecord, test);
          byte[] messageBytes = serializer.serialize(testConversionTopicName,message);
          LOGGER.info("send Started , {}",test.getId());
          ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, byte[]>> future = highSpeedAvroKafkaTemplate.send(testConversionTopicName, objectKeyRecord.toString(), messageBytes);
          LOGGER.info("send Done , {}",test.getId());
          future.addCallback(new KafkaProducerFutureCallback(kafkaSender, testConversionTopicName, objectKeyRecord.toString(), message));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you profiled your application? e.g. with YourKit.

I suspect it's the Avro serializer; I am able to send 15,000 1000 byte messages in 274ms.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50060086Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50060086Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            String payload = new String(new byte[999]);
            StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
            watch.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15_000; i++) {
                template.send("so50060086a", "" + i + payload);
            }
            watch.stop();
            System.out.println(watch.prettyPrint());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so50060086a", 1, (short) 1);
    }
}
```

and

```
StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 274
```

Comment: Gary , I tried changing to the ByteArraySerializer and still see send call takes more time. Updated my post with details.Try to find some profiler so that I can use it to see whats happening

Comment: I just noticed you have `acks = all` - I just changed my test to use that and my test went up to 436ms (topic replicated on 3 brokers). However, my 3 brokers are on localhost. `acks=all` is expensive - how many broker instances do you have? Is there a good network between them?

Comment: @Garry we have five brokers and each topic is replicated in 3 brokers. All of them are running in AWS same region.

Comment: Probably a poor network problem - either between brokers or between your client and the brokers. Even if I add a `get()` to the future (waiting for all acks) on each send, it only takes 1-2ms per send.

Comment: I am still thinking on why it is taking long on the call for send which is an async method

Comment: Kerberos could also be slowing down things. Can u remove security for a moment, and see how it goes, and ofcourse Acks= ALL, could be a possible reason too.